# Does PDF.js raise an event as I browse between pages?

Tags: javascript, pushstate, pdf.js

Does PDF.js raise an event as I browse between pages?

Basically I want to update the URL and add to pushstate when I browse between pages in a PDF.js document.

Does PDF.js raise an event as I browse between pages, and if so what is the event called?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, there is an event named `pagechange`.

You can use it like that:

```
document.addEventListener('pagechange', function(e) {
  if (e.pageNumber !== e.previousPageNumber) {
    console.log('page changed from ' + e.previousPageNumber + ' to ' + e.pageNumber);
  }
});
```

Open [the viewer](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) and drop the code above into the console, and see what happens!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks very much!

Comment: In v2.1.233 of pdf.js you have to set `PDFViewerApplication.eventBus._dispatchToDOM` to `true` for this to work. It's false by default.

Answer (score 6):

Now in v2.13.216 of pdf.js, took from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/9527)

```
document.addEventListener("webviewerloaded", () => {
    PDFViewerApplication.initializedPromise.then(() => {
        PDFViewerApplication.eventBus.on("documentloaded", (e) => {
            console.log("The document has now been loaded");
        });

        PDFViewerApplication.eventBus.on("pagechanging", (e) => {
            console.log('pagechanging, from ' + e.previous + ' to ' + e.pageNumber);
        });

        PDFViewerApplication.eventBus.on("scalechanging", (e) => {
            console.log('scalechanging, scale ' + e.scale);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: UPDATE Sep 2022 : this is the right answer for v2.16.105. Since eventBusDispatchToDOM is deprecated. https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/9527#issuecomment-604318161

Answer (score 4):

Now in v2.1.233 of pdf.js, the event is `pagechanging`.

Answer (score 4):

The following code worked for me -

```
window.PDFViewerApplication.eventBus.on('pagechanging', function pagechange(evt) { 
   console.log(evt)
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `eventBusDispatchToDOM: true` in your `viewer.js` file.